# Matplotlib candlestick axis plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to create a basic candle stick graph using matplotlib, but am having problems displaying the actual graph.  I'm pretty sure the problem is i'm not configuring the x & y axis correctly, I have been trying for the last couple days but am lost.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjBkc.png) is what the graph looks like currently:

[image: current graph]

The data is all between 6:30 - 1:00 (pacific time), i'm trying to get the graph to format so that it only shows that range.

I currently have an array of 390 tuples, each tuple holding information for each minute the market is open.

first 20 tuples:

```
(735788.2708333334, 100.42199999999998, 100.37066666666666, 100.49666666666667, 100.30999999999999)
(735788.2715277778, 100.40166666666667, 99.80386666666668, 100.50318, 99.61001333333334)
(735788.2722222222, 99.82835999999999, 99.71597333333334, 100.01999333333333, 99.43113333333332)
(735788.2729166667, 99.73700000000002, 99.75814666666669, 100.08185333333331, 99.42368000000002)
(735788.2736111111, 99.79395999999998, 99.73145333333332, 100.03351333333333, 99.44720000000001)
(735788.2743055555, 99.70568666666667, 99.77659333333332, 99.89994000000002, 99.52147333333333)
(735788.275, 99.74577333333336, 99.63916, 99.90475333333332, 99.50369333333335)
(735788.2756944444, 99.63131333333332, 99.79678, 99.93578666666666, 99.51455333333334)
(735788.276388889, 99.79278666666667, 99.82032666666667, 100.00658666666668, 99.60532666666667)
(735788.2770833333, 99.78903333333334, 99.55625333333334, 99.8616, 99.39334666666666)
(735788.2777777778, 99.54983333333334, 99.6574, 99.78999999999999, 99.38213999999999)
(735788.2784722223, 99.65650666666667, 99.72088666666669, 99.88065333333333, 99.52334666666664)
(735788.2791666667, 99.71439333333333, 99.73757333333334, 99.87037333333335, 99.53099999999999)
(735788.2798611111, 99.75731999999999, 99.71152000000001, 99.87126666666664, 99.55641333333334)
(735788.2805555556, 99.72598666666667, 99.69014666666668, 99.86319333333333, 99.49409333333331)
(735788.28125, 99.69524, 99.62354000000002, 99.87518, 99.41418666666667)
(735788.2819444444, 99.59366000000001, 99.57455333333334, 99.74746, 99.42263333333335)
(735788.2826388889, 99.56687333333335, 99.64080000000003, 99.77255333333333, 99.43100000000001)
(735788.2833333333, 99.62504666666668, 99.72166666666664, 99.81258666666668, 99.51756666666667)
(735788.2840277777, 99.70745333333333, 99.76073333333332, 99.91593999999999, 99.59593333333332)
```

tuple format is: (time, open, close, high, low)

time is date2num

Code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize(10,5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.85, 0.7])
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='out', width=2, length=8, labelsize=12, pad=8)
ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(2)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)
ax.set_xticklabels(timeAvg, rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
ax.set_ylabel('$', size='20')
ax.set_ylim([75,105])

candlestick(ax, listoftuples, width=0.5, colorup='g', colordown='r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Should your example tuple have a fifth element?

Comment: @Engineero your right, i accidentally left one out when i was copying it over.  fixed it.

Comment: It looks like your data is going in formatted badly, but close enough that it is not erroring.  With out seeing your data it is hard to sort out what is going wrong.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html That is what you should be seeing

Comment: @tcaswell included the first 20 tuples.